# authentication-success-handler-ref is incompatible with login-processing-url?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

spring-security.xml:

```
<form-login        
        login-page="/admin/login"
        login-processing-url="/admin/postlogin"
        authentication-failure-url="/admin/login?error=true"
        default-target-url="/admin/dashboard"
        username-parameter="username" 
        password-parameter="password"
        authentication-success-handler-ref="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler"/>
```

CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler:

```
@Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, Authentication authentication) 
        throws IOException,ServletException {

     HttpSession session = httpServletRequest.getSession(); 

     session.setAttribute("countTodayInterviews", interviewService.countTodayInterviews()); 
     session.setAttribute("countNewCandidates", jobSeekerService.countNewCandidates());

}
```

Without `authentication-success-handler-ref` it works fine and I get redirected to the dashboard, but with `authentication-success-handler-ref` I reach to a blank page on link `/admin/postlogin`. I need those attributes in my session, and like this it should call just once. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a redirect to proper URL from onAuthenticationSuccess() method of the custom handler.

```
private RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();

@Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, 
  HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException {
    //Your custom stuff
    handle(request, response, authentication);
}

protected void handle(HttpServletRequest request, 
    HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException {
    String targetUrl = "";//Place your target url detection logic here. 

    redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, targetUrl);
}
```

Comment: I cant do any redirect because of implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler it support just void function

Comment: I am asking to do a redirect, not a return. As you are implementing your own success handler, it is your responsibility to determine the next url, if it is a success. Will add some eamples.